# Robotframework - using environment variables in a variable file

Tags: robotframework

I would like to construct a variable for RobotFramework within
the variable file but using the Linux environmental variable.
Could you advise on the syntax please ??
My current attempts with this:

```
vif_vlan       = "110"

path_scripts   = '%{MY_DIR}/my_path/scripts'

remote_path    = "/home/mcast/mgen"
```

end up in not expanding the env variable `%{MY_DIR}` ...

Tx

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are in the `environ` dictionary of the `os` module:

```
import os
path_scripts = os.path.join(os.environ['MY_DIR']', 'my_path', 'scripts')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is almost correct - Not for Python, but for Robot Framework.
In your `.robot` files, you can retrieve environment variables as follows:

```
** Variables **
| ${MY_PATH_TO_SCRIPTS} | %{MY_DIR}/my_path/scripts
```